# Getting an element from array in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart, How to access the element from the array which is created like below?

```
final Object? elements;    
elements= ["element1" , "element2" , "element3"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
convertObject(Object obj) {
  if (obj is bool) {
    return obj;
  } else if (obj is List) {
    print("ListType");
    return obj.map((e) => e.toString()).toList(); // creating list by converting string
  }
  ///... do for others

}


void main(List<String> args) {
  final Object? elements;
  elements = ["element1", "element2", "element3"];

  final convertedDB = convertObject(elements);
  print(convertedDB);
  print("0 index item ${convertedDB[0]}");
}
```

> Everything you can place in a variable is an object, and every object is an instance of a class. Even numbers, functions, and null are objects. With the exception of null (if you enable sound null safety), all objects inherit from the Object class.

More about [static-checking](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-using-dynamic-unless-you-want-to-disable-static-checking)

[built-in-types](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#built-in-types)

> Lists (List, also known as arrays)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. How does it answer the OP's question?

Comment: I've used `convertObject()` to describe the possible cases while using `Object`, then applied use cases on `main()` method. Next note described about `Object` and included link is to check more about `Object` and `dataType`. And I thought it will be enough including link to describe the concept. But it would be better to describe the converted list as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, no need to declare the type:

```
final elements = ["element1" , "element2" , "element3"];
```

The compiler can determine the type: `List<String>`

To access the first element of the array (usually called List in Dart):

```
elements.first // same as elements[0]
```

To access the last element of the array:

```
elements.last // same as elements[elements.length - 1]
```

To access the `n`th element of the array (where 0 is the first index):

```
elements[n]
```